# HighFive - read dataset into Eigen3 Matrix

Tags: c++, hdf5, eigen3

I'm experimenting with the header-only library HighFive, which provides a more convenient interface to libhdf5. There's a provided example showing how to populate a DataSet from an Eigen::MatrixXd. I'm interested in going in the other direction - filling an Eigen Matrix from a DataSet. I've tried this naive approach:

```
HighFive::File file(strFileName, HighFive::File::ReadOnly);
auto dataset = file.getDataSet("/data");
Eigen::MatrixXd m(rowDim, colDim);
dataset.read(m);
```

The compiler trace shows this; `static assertion failed: The type is not trivially copyable` from the point where I'm trying to invoke the `read()`. I should mention that when I installed HighFive, I did follow the instructions to enable Eigen support.

Comment: I never used HighFive, but perhaps the raw interface is an option for you: https://github.com/BlueBrain/HighFive/blob/master/src/examples/read_write_raw_ptr.cpp

Comment: @chtz That's a possibility, all right. I'm still hoping that there's a way of more-or-less directly populating an Eigen Matrix,

Comment: If what you are doing is documented behavior, but does not work, you should probably file an issue at their github page. But you could first [edit] this question to provide a proper [mre].

Comment: It does look like the H5Easy APIs demonstrate reading into an Eigen Matrix. I'll give that a shot next.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's a function in the H5Easy namespace that does just what I want. Rather than the approach I tried in the question, the following does work:

```
#include <highfive/H5File.hpp>
#include <highfive/H5Easy.hpp>

HighFive::File file(strFileName, HighFive::File::ReadOnly);
Eigen::MatrixXd = HFEasy::load<Eigen::MatrixXd>(file, "/data");
```